# How to display saved cards with Stripe elements?

Tags: angular, mobile, capacitor, card

I am using Ionic capacitor with Angular to create a Stripe checkout page on my mobile application using Stripe elements.

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.stripe = await loadStripe(environment.stripe);

    this.order = await firstValueFrom(this.orderService.getOneById(this.route.snapshot.params["order_id"]));

    if (this.order.data.session_id) {
      this.client_secret = this.order.data.session_id;
    } else {
      console.log(this.order.data.id);
      await firstValueFrom(this.cartService.createStripeIntent({ order_id: this.order.data.id })).then(async (res) => {
        console.log("RESPONSE", res);
        this.client_secret = res.client_secret;
      });
    }

    this.elements = this.stripe!.elements({
      clientSecret: this.client_secret,
    });

    const payment = this.elements.create("payment");

    payment.mount("#payment-element");

    this.cart_item = this.checkProductQuantity(this.order.item);
    this.calculateShipping();
    this.category_shipping_data = Object.values(this.category_shipping_data);
    this.getTotal();
  }

  async handleSubmit() {
    this.elements.submit();

    this.stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(this.client_secret).then(({ paymentIntent }: any) => {
      switch (paymentIntent.status) {
        case "succeeded":
          this.message = "Payment succeeded!";
          break;
        case "processing":
          this.message = "Your payment is processing.";
          break;
        default:
          this.message = "Something went wrong.";
          break;
      }
    });

    if (!this.stripe) {
      return;
    }

    this.isProcessing = true;

    const res = await this.stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements: this.elements,
      clientSecret: this.client_secret,
      confirmParamas: {
        return_url: "http://localhost:3000/",
      },
      redirect: "if_required",
    });

    console.log(res);
    if (res.error) {
      if (res.error.type === "card_error" || res.error.type === "validation_error") {
        this.message = res.error.message;
        this.isProcessing = false;
      }
    } else if (res.paymentIntent) {
      this.router.navigate(["order-placed", this.order.data.id]);
    }

    this.isProcessing = false;
  }
```

This is my code and is working well atm. What I want to do is: if a user already paid once, next time he pays, I want it to save his card and create a saved card element like in the stripe checkout session version on the web. Is there a saved cards element in stripe, or how would I go about doing that?

Any reccomendations?
Thank you.